# Xamarin PCL intercept menu back button pressed

Tags: ios, events, xamarin, navigation

There seems to be quite a lot of buzz on the web about this issue for iOS. I have examined a few articles but a lot of them are dated quite a while ago so maybe there is some fresh info.

I have a PCL project and an iOS project in Xamarin forms. The code is 99% in the PCL. I want to override the back button pressed event. I mean the back button in the top standard iOS menu.

Here are some solutions that I came across.

1) The OnBackButtonPressed() only works for hardware button on Android.

2) The only other way I found here https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/ is to override the back button click on the default back button in the UINavigationBar.

3) Use OnDissapearing but I can't do that because I only want to implement an event when navigation occurs to a previous page but OnDissapearing fires out if we navigate forward as well.

I wonder if there might be a simple elegant quick way that I didn't come across that some one is using. Thanks.

Comment: Another idea, mock the navigation bar and put the "Back button" as a regular button.

Comment: After I wrote this I also thought of a hack like making a boolean flag false if navigation moves ahead and true if navigation pop async happens and using it to filter my action at overriden OnDissapearing.

Comment: Its really disappointing though there isn’t a simple event to hook up to, seems like a widely required scenario.

Comment: I think your second solution can achieve your effect perfectly. Why not use it? And it is the only solution I thought.

Comment: Yeah well it does look like the most complete choice but I actually went with the flags option because it was simply faster although it does feel like a bit of a hack. So I am using OnDissapearing and then if Navigation occurs to a place where I don't want it to fire I just set a false flag on a global static variable and set it back to true on an OnAppearing for the origin page so if I actually Navigate somewhere where I want the OnDissapearing to fire the variable will not be set to false and will be true. Hope I made sense)